# Zeitwerk + Rails 6.1 - controller modules not autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

I'm working with a legacy app with controllers where the basic CRUD actions are split into modules. The modules are within the `app/controllers` folder and each module is separately included in the controller class.

(Yes, it's because the modules are long. I know, fat controllers. I didn't write them. I'm going to be refactoring them, but first i just want to see if i can get the app to load under Zeitwerk correctly.)

```
app/
  controllers/
    posts_controller/
      destroy.rb
      edit_and_update.rb
      index.rb
      new_and_create.rb
      show.rb
    posts_controller.rb
```

The modules are included in the controller class:

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  include Index
  include Show
  include NewAndCreate
  include EditAndUpdate
  include Destroy
```

The modules are like:

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller/index.rb
module PostsController::Index
```

When I run

```
rails zeitwerk:check
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
All is good!
```

However, when I interrupt my `posts_controller_test` via `binding.break` and check the controller class itself:

```
(rdbg) Post.const_get("PostsController")
eval error: uninitialized constant PostsController::Index
```

From what I understand, everything in `app/controllers` is autoloaded, and my filenames and classes correspond. So I don't believe this should be necessary, but if I add the `app/controllers/posts_controller` sub-folder to `config.eager_load_paths`, i get

```
eval error: expected file .../app/controllers/posts_controller/index.rb to define constant Index, but didn't
```

What am I doing wrong here? (other than having fat controllers!)

Comment: Everything is working fine, zeitwerk:check actually loaded the controller (it eager loads the application). The problem here seems related to the breakpoint itself, possibly due to https://github.com/ruby/debug/issues/408, which in principle is solved. Which version of Ruby is your application using?

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I'm using rvm 3.0.4 — looks like the issue is fixed, but maybe only if i move to ruby 3.1?

I've read somewhere that it might be better to stay on 3.0.4 until after moving to Rails 7. But, if Rails 6.1 works well with Ruby 3.1 i can try for that upgrade.

Comment: Exactly, the fix is in Ruby 3.1. So, at least, you have the tranquility that the application is good, only there's that gotcha if you set a breakpoint and need to autoload a namespace that is defined in a file. Alternatively, you can launch a console with binding.pry or somesuch, not a debugger, but at least you get a REPL.

Comment: Do not use `::` when defining constants. Use explicit nesting - `class PostsController; module Index`. While the former is often mistaken to be a shorthand syntax it doesn't set the correct module nesting and is an open invitation for bugs. https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: Rails just generates code with broken nesting since the code templates would need to be more complex to get it right and it works most of the time - until it doesn't.

Comment: I disagree. You can perfectly use `::` after a class or module keyword, and I don't think that recommendation makes sense. The nesting is not "broken", the nesting is what it needs to be, and you as a Ruby programmer use relative constants according to the nesting you chose.

Comment: I have to add that the classic autoloader could not deal with arbitrary nestings correctly, and the recommendation was to avoid `::` because then it could work better. This is no longer needed with Zeitwerk, any nesting works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this discussion, both of you. I do remember the issue of explicit nesting that @max mentions — changing to explicit nesting was one of the things I tried to debug the issue — and it's also good to have confirmation that it makes no difference to zeitwerk.

Comment: This discussion is moving a bit off topic but Zeitwerk can deal with the fact the "Foo::Bar" would cause a missing constant since it has a map of your classes and their source location. To take that as a reason to not nest your code properly is pretty silly IMHO. The whole reason to nest a class is so you can reference constants in the same nesting and encapsulate your code.